# Connect the sides of two datagrids

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having some difficulties with formatting two datagrids so that they resize appropriately when their containing window is resized. Currently, the two datagrids are sitting side by side so that they nearly touch in the center of the window.

The top, bottom, and edge-facing sides of each datagrid are connected/linked to the nearest side of the window (I used the link icon in the center of each side). Is there a way to make the center facing sides of the datagrids connect to each other (or to the center of the window), so that when the window is resized, these center-facing sides stay close to the center?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How about you post your XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you ask your question, I believe you're coming from WinForms development. In WPF, things are a lot different. I would suggest that you get a WPF book and start writing the XAML directly and not use the designer.

For your problem, the solution is pretty straightforward. All you have to do is use a grid with 2 columns:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0"></DataGrid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The `Width="*"` attribute will make sure that the columns are the same width and that they take up all available space.

The trouble with using the designer is that when you do that, it will start putting hardcoded margins and sizes in your XAML and you will lose all of the cool auto-sizing features of WPF. Therefore I strongly suggest writing XAML manually and not using the designer (except to see what your window/control looks like).

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. And I appreciate the advice about avoiding the designer. Incidentally, I've only ever worked with WPF and ASP.Net, but I'm  still quite green, which might explain some of the awkwardness in how my question was framed.